# Use Vectors to Locate a Point

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have no idea where to even start, please help!

Find the point R on ℓ that is closest to Q.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykBGf.gif)

Q = (0, 2, 0), ℓ with equation [x y z] = [2 2 2] + t[-4 0 6]

Find the answer in the form of (x, y, z)

Comment: Make use of the fact that QR is perpendicular to l.

Comment: So would I start by finding the length of QR?

Answer (score 0):

If you had the equation of the line QR, you would be able to find R by finding the intersection between QR and l. In order to find the equation of QR, you need a point and a direction. You have the point, because QR passes through Q.

So you just need a direction vector. Note first that your problem is 2D: everything is in the $y=2$ plane. You know that the direction of QR is perpendicular to the direction of l, and you know the direction of $l$, it is $[-4,0,6]$. In [2D, this is simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularVector.html): $[a,b]$ is perpendicular to $[-b,a]$. So the direction of QR is $[-6,0,-4]$. You now know $QR$, find the intersection with l.